# User accounts settings annoyance

Tags: windows-8, uac

I've been dealing with this problem for a while now and don't know how to fix it. SO every time I try to open "change user account settings" nothing happens when I click on it, same with change account type nothing happens when I change to administator it justs stays the same and doesnt change even when I try to open pictures a message comes up saying "this app can't be opened when uac is disabled" please if anyone could help i'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The best that explain this is a virus or someone have disabled UAC through the Group Policy Editor :

Try this :

1. Go to Run (windows Button + R) type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
2. In the Group Policy Editor window, browse to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options.

3.In the right pane scroll to find the User Access Control policies (they're down at the bottom of the window). You need to configure the following policies:

[image]

4. You'll need to reboot your computers.

I hope this will solve your problem